# Running buildozer in docker

Tags: docker, kivy, buildozer

Hi,

I've built the buildozer app according to the GitHub [README](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer#buildozer-docker-image), `pwd` is my project directory:

```
$ docker run --volume "$(pwd)":/home/user/hostcwd buildozer android debug
```

First time this command downloaded all the SDKs, built a lot of dependencies and finally built an apk file in `pwd/bin`, which is an easily expected behavior. I tried to build the apk again with the same command line, and it started the process of downloading SDKs again, which I aborted. What is the right way of docker running buildozer routinely?

It turned out that all the SDKs and things live now in the project directory (`pwd/.buildozer`) directory, which does not seem right. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Buildozer seem to save the SDK, NDK and Ant (and maybe other dependencies that my build didn't need) inside `/home/user/.buildozer`.

Try attaching a volume to this path as well, like the example below (replacing the `/path/to/your/cache/buildozer` with wherever you want to store it on your local machine):

`docker run -v /path/to/your/cache/buildozer:/home/user/.buildozer -v $(pwd):/home/user/hostcwd kivy/buildozer android debug`

The second time you run it should be much faster. (Also note that used the `kivy/buildozer` image from Docker Hub in that command, so expect some download time if you don't have it in cache).

Comment: Your instructions have been merged into the official README file.
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/1619